# findFirst does not working with 3 filters on Prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, prisma

I'm having this problem when I want to check if I have at least one record with the parameters. With 2 filters it works fine, but with 3 it's not working.

```js
await prismaClient.t_endereco
                .findFirst({
                    where: {
                        logradouro, (string)
                        bairro, (string)
                        numero, (number)
                    },
                })
```

the condition to update the record is not having another identical.

i tried to use AND too:

```js
await prismaClient.t_endereco
                .findFirst({
                    where: {
                        AND:[
                              {logradouro}, 
                              {bairro}, 
                              {numero},  
                            ]
                        
                    },
                })
```

same issue.

someone to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follow:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

prisma.category.findFirst({
  where: {
    OR: [
      { id: 2 },
      { name: 'new' },
      { description: 'd1' },
    ],
  },
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

[You can check the documentation for more information](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#or)